# ERROR: function addgeometrycolumn does not exist: When trying to import file into POSTGIS database by QGIS DB Manager

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis

I am trying to import a shapefile via db manager in QGIS to my POSTGIS database but I get an error, that I do not know to resolve:

```
ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('demoschema','Bomen',NULL,31370,'MU...
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So what do I need to do?

Answer (score 6):

Without postgis extension in postgresSQL, if you try to add any spatial layers to postgresSQL , you get above error.

In pgadmin right click on extensions and check whether postgis extension is saved or not.
if in extensions postgis option is absent ,you can follow these steps to
install postgis in postgres https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afK8GWpb8RU

Comment: Or in SQL command : `CREATE EXTENSION POSTGIS` in the database. See https://postgis.net/documentation/getting_started/

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd parameter is the column name, which is Null in your case. Make sure you specify it in the interface

[image]